# How can I localize and translate the entire system instead of partial localization?

Tags: sensenet

Using SenseNet's build-in localization feature placed in */Root/Localization*, we've been able to translate only 50% of the system but not all parts of the system.

Is it possible to translate and localize the entire system using SenseNet's build-in tool or I've to do it manually?

Comment: Have you tried to switch to 'Resource editor mode'? It can be found on the portal remote control (it is the last button actually). Not all the things can be localized this way, but maybe it will help to reduce the number of things that you cannot localize this way and we can help you to solve the remaining cases.

Comment: Yes, I tried the "Resource editor mode" and as you know, it's impossible to localize the whole system in this way. so how can I solve the remaining cases?

Answer (score 1):

1. The menu is a list of DisplayNames of content items, so to localize menu, you have to localize the DisplayNames this way:

   $ResourceClass,ResourceKey
2. If you haven't made custom views for rendering forms, the labels are the DisplayNames and the Descriptions of the fields that are defined in the CTD. For further info check this article about [How to internationalize Content Type Definition](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_internationalize_Content_Type_Definition)
3. If you've made custom view for a form, you can localize labels in your custom view. Check this article about [How to internationalize Sense/Net](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_internationalize_Sense/Net#Internationalize_content_views)

Please specify what do you mean by Control Panel and I will add the solution by editing my answer

Comment: I mean the pages that the admin users have access, such as System Version, Settings and any other pages that the end-user does not access.

Comment: Can I localize the whole Sense/Net using the approach you mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, the article [How to internationalize Sense/Net](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_internationalize_Sense/Net#Internationalize_content_views) is a good starting point on how to localize various type of things in sensenet (content views, content type definitions, etc)